# Can heartbleed be used to de-anonymize you by browsing a site via Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, deanonymization

Assuming that you have information in your ram that would identify who you are, and you are using the Tor browser but your pc is running a vulnerable version of openssl, could your memory be dumped by visiting a malicious site? Or does the TBB use it's own ssl tools rather than what you have installed on your system?

Comment: In general OpenSSL clients are vulnerable as explained in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55119/does-the-heartbleed-vulnerability-affect-clients-as-severely but does not affect NSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not with TBB.

TBB is based on Firefox ESR which doesn't use OpenSSL but NSS to do SSL/TLS.

Other software that uses a vulnerable Version of OpenSSL could be exploited by a malicious server.